# Como hacer que funcione un ONCHANGE de un SELECT al cargar la pagina

Tags: php, html, ajax, highcharts

lo que tengo inicialmente es un select el cual muestra las ultimas semanas que se reflejaran en las incidencias, el index es de esta manera:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>ejemplo</title>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/funciones2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 1000px;height: 330px;margin: 0 auto;border: solid 3px; border-color: #ff3333"> 
      <div ><label>ultimas:</label><select name="semanita" id="semanita" onchange="week();">
          <option value="">Seleccione:</option>
                                <?php
                                $acu=1;
                               $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
                               mysql_select_db("inci",$con);
                               $consulta_semana= mysql_query("SELECT MAX(semana) as y FROM registro_tecno "); 
                               while($data= mysql_fetch_array($consulta_semana)){
                                   $semanax=$data['y'];                                 
                                  }
                                while($acu<=$semanax){
                                    echo "<option value='".$acu."' $selected>".$acu."</option>"; 
                                    $acu++;
                                }
                              ?>       
  </select><label>..semanas</label></div>
    <div id="graficacombo" ></div>
  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

entonces envio el valor seleccionado a funciones2.js

```
function week(){
 var parametros={
    "semanita": $("#semanita").val(),
 }
 $.ajax({
    data: parametros,
    url:"ejemplo.php",
    type:"POST",
    beforeSend: function(){
        $("#graficacombo").html('<center><img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="20" heigh="20"></center>');
    },
    success: function(vista){
        $("#graficacombo").html(vista);
     }
    });
   }
```

entonces en mi pagina ejemplo.php ejecutara el codigo y mostrara los resultados en una grafica de HIGHCHARTS, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
  include("conexion.php");

     $semanal=$_POST['semanita'];   
     $sla2="incidencia";
       $a2="";
       $xx=31-(int)$semanal;
        for ($j=$xx+1; $j <=31 ; $j++) { 

            $result_inc2 =$con->query("SELECT count(incidencia) as ver2 FROM `registro_tecno_bk_2` WHERE semana=".$j."");
            while($row_inc2= mysqli_fetch_array($result_inc2, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
              {
                $inc2= $row_inc2["ver2"];
                $a2=$a2.$inc2.",";               
              }
        } 


  mysqli_close($con);
?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    $('#graficacombo').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
           width: '980',
           height: '300',
        },
        title: {
            text: 'CLASIFICACION POR SEMANA'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'de las Incidencias'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [<?php for($y=$xx+1;$y<=31;$y++){ echo "'Semana ".$y."',";}?>
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Incidencias '
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.0f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                },
            }
        },
        series: [
        {
            name: <?php  echo "'".$sla2."',";  ?>
            data: [ <?php echo $a2; ?> ]
        }, 
        ]
    });
});


    </script>
```

entonces al cargar el index.php, inicialmente se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y despues de seleccionar un valor del SELECT, me muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

entonces mi pregunta seria la siguiente, como haria para que desde que cargue la pagina(localhost/ejemplo/index.php) me muestre en la grafica 1 como en la grafica 2, trate poniendo en una OPTION "selected", pero no salio, esto creo que se debe a que el onchange actua de otra manera, y es dando un click al select, pero como haria para que desde que cargue la pagina me muestre los ultimos 7 valores.

Comment: No debes agregar código en el front de tu pagina, con jQuery puedes hacerlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es que cargue seleccionando la opción 7 puedes probar algo como esto:

```js
$( window ).load(function() {
  $('#options option[value="7"]').prop('selected', true);
  var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
  evt.initEvent("change", false, true);
  document.getElementById('options').dispatchEvent(evt);
});

$( "#options" ).change(function() {
  alert($('#options').val()); //AGREGAS AQUI TU FUNCIÓN week();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="options">
  <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>
```

Comment: es que no es que estoy agregando codigo, sino que en mi tabla tengo una columna "semana", la cual me selecciona la cantidad de semanas que van hasta la fechas, en este caso son 31, por eso hago el buscador

Comment: gracias por responder, me sirvio ese script

Comment: De nada amigo exitos pues